# Amazon Linux Version Details

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-linux, amazon-ami

I am getting acquainted with AWS and I'm using Amazon Linux on EC2 to build a LAMP stack.

I read somewhere on the AWS site that the AMI 2013.09 had PHP 5.5 but when I installed it and followed the LAMP tutorial, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html, I found that version 5.3 was installed.

Have I missed something?  Or misread something perhaps?

I can no longer find the URL that detailed what was in 2013.09.  Is there resource that details what's in each release?

Comment: No idea why you got downvoted (twice!).  This is a good question; upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Linux provides PHP 5.3, 5.4, and 5.5 as options. `yum install php55` will get the 5.5 version. `yum search php` will give you the various packages in a nice list to review.

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09 Release Notes](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2013.09-release-notes/)  - found with a google search for 'AMI 2013.09'.

Answer (score 1):

*Steps (Use **sudo** only if required)*

**1) Remove OLD Apache**

```
sudo service httpd stop
sudo yum erase httpd httpd-tools apr apr-util
```

**2) Remove OLD PHP**

```
sudo yum remove php-*
```

**if it´s a clean installation start from here:**

**3) Install PHP 5.6 (Apache 2.4 will be automatically installed with this)**

```
sudo yum install php56
```

**4) Make sure all the required PHP extensions are installed**

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

**5) If not then install them using**

```
sudo yum install php56-xml php56-xmlrpc php56-soap php56-gd
```

**6) To list the other available php extensions**

```
yum search php56
```

**7) PHP 5.6 MySQL extension (Assume you have already installed MySQL)**

```
sudo yum install php56-mysqlnd
```

*(NOTE: it is not php56-mysql)*

**8) Start / Restart Apache**

```
sudo service httpd start
sudo service httpd restart
```

**9) Check the version**

```
php -v
httpd -v
```