# Update PHP with yum on Amazon Linux

Tags: yum, amazon-linux, amazon-ami

I have Amazon Linux on EC2, AMI 2013.09.  I followed the LAMP install tutorial, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html, and ended up with PHP5.3 installed.

In answer to this question here, [Amazon Linux Version Details](https://serverfault.com/questions/566476/amazon-linux-version-details), ceejay0z explains that I can upgrade to PHP5.5 using `yum install php55`.  When I do, however, I get errors relating to conflicts (at the end of dependency checking).

So, my question is, how do I proceed from here?  Do I want to erase the existing PHP install, then install the new one?  Upgrade?  Update?  Update-to?  (In case it's not obvious, I have not used yum before...)

Comment: you should list your errors so that people can help

Comment: how did you get this working?

Comment: Chiquis, see answer below.  That's as far as I got.  The next problem I struck was that the PDO driver for MySQL was not in the repo, (not for 5.5 anyhow).  I trashed the machine and went to Ubuntu 12.04.  Happy days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I seem to have got this working.  Not 100% sure how, but I think I had to erase php and httpd, then install php55.  Not sure if I had to install httpd24 separately?

Comment: You shouldn't post edits to your question as answers.

Answer (score 23):

Worked for me:

```
yum remove php httpd php-cli php-xml php-common httpd-tools
yum install php55 php55-mysql php55-pdo
```

Comment: I get "No package php55-mysql available."

Comment: @MarkKasson Try php55-mysqlnd or php-mysqlnd. I think I might have been suppressing errors when I ran that, sorry

Comment: My particular need solved with `sudo yum install php-mysqli -y`.  I recall seeing that it loaded php-mysqlnd.

Comment: Can I do this with #yum upgrade php5.6 ? will this upgrade php5.3 to php5.6 without dependencies issues ? or removing 5.3 in installing 5.6 is the only better way