# Full Update to PHP5.5 on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have been trying to get LAMP install upgraded to PHP5.5, Apache 2.4, on Amazon Linux.  Per this earlier question, [Update PHP with yum on Amazon Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/566527/update-php-with-yum-on-amazon-linux), I thought I had it beat, but clearly that's not the case.

At the moment I am trying to install the PDO package and I'm getting the following errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php55-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.28-1.2.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried the two fixes suggested in the error messages, but that didn't help.  Also, tried to erase php-common-5.3....  but could not.  Could erase php-common, but that would erase the 5.5 version with it.  Any ideas?

Once I am over this hurdle, it's possible I'll strike other hurdles too, so the bigger question is... Has anyone done this before?  And perhaps logged the steps in a blog article?

I am using AMI 2013.09.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go ahead and do `sudo yum remove php-common`, it will be installed again when you do `sudo yum install php55`. Same goes for any other conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package php55-mysqlnd. I believe this will provide mysql support to PDO.

Comment: I see a php55-pdo.x86_64 package....